# How to add hook on process kill in bash with a custom bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a django server. On start of server, I would like to start docker containers, and on kill of server I would like to stop docker containers

Now I have:

1. rsAlias.sh:

   `#/usr/bin/zsh
    docker ps --filter name=$(pwd | ~/projectName.js) -aq | xargs docker start`
2. projectName.js:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/node
   const readline = require('readline');

   const rl = readline.createInterface({
     input: process.stdin,
     output: process.stdout
   });

   rl.question('' ,(answer) => {
     const currentProjectName = answer.split('/').slice(-1)[0]

     console.log(currentProjectName);
     rl.close();
   });
   ```
3. runserver.sh

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/zsh

   ~/rsAlias.sh;
   source .venv/bin/activate;
   ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000;
   ```

and I execute runserver.sh if I want to start server

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do it this way, rather than telling systemd your containers are strict dependencies of the server, and letting *it* start them up and shut them down appropriately? Or, heck, put all three services under a target, and start/stop/query the target. Mucking about with `ps`, or even `docker ps`, makes for scripts with unintended sensitivity to current system state, and thus for hard-to-reproduce bugs; whereas `systemctl start foo` doesn't care about the current state; it's purely a declarative statement of what intended state should be.

Comment: (See https://github.com/ibuildthecloud/systemd-docker re: wrapping docker containers as systemd services).